# Bash script print error and exits or continues

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, terminal

I am new to bash and shell scripting. I have a command that I want to execute in my Makefile. But if the command throws and error than I want the Makefile to throw and error and exit. Else I want it to continue to the next commands.

Here is the psuedocode of what I am trying to achieve:

```
some-makefile-command:
    if command fails execution:
         print the command's error message
         exit
    else:
         execute other commands
```

Comment: This is the default behavior of make if you simply list your commands in the recipe: stop on first error. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to an arbitrary if statement in a makefile, you have to be aware that every recipe line in a makefile target is run in a new shell.  So for example:

```
all:
    if [ $blah ]; then
        echo something
    fi
```

has three separate recipe lines.  The first line `if [ $blah ]; then` would be passed to a shell instance, which would then complain that it's not a complete statement (it would not pass the other lines to that instance of the shell), and it would fail.    The fix is to use concatenation (a trailing `\` at the end of each line) to make all of the lines into a single line as so:

```
all:
    if [ $blah ]; then \
        echo something; \
    fi
```

This would pass `if [blah]; then  echo something;  fi` to the shell instance, which the shell instance could understand, and would be able to process.

Notice the `;` after `echo something` -- because you're concatenating lines, and there's no actual newline after `echo something`, you need the `;` to delimit the action from the `fi` statement.

--- EDIT ----

outside of this, you could just do:

```
some-makefile-command:
    command
    #other commands
```

if recipe `command` fails (returns non-zero), then make will stop processing the rule, and exit (no need to explicitly call exit).  Otherwise it will continue to run the rest of the commands.   If you want to output something special if the command fails you could do:

```
some-makefile-command:
    command || echo "something" && false
```

Notice that the recipe as a whole must fail for make to stop processing, and because `echo "..."` always returns true, you need the `&& false` at the end to make the entire statement return false if `command` fails

Comment: Is there a way I can capture the output from command and echo that in your last code example?

Comment: The output of `command` would be echoed in the make logs by default.   You have to explicitly pipe the output to `/dev/null` to suppress that -- i.e. `command > /dev/null || echo failed && false`.   One extra thing thing that would likely be of interest to you is the [@ symbol in front of a recipe will suppress the recipe line from being echoed to the output](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Echoing)

Comment: Although my `command` throws an error. My Makefile builds successfully. Can I have it print the stderr of my command and have the Makefile throw an error? However, I want the Makefile to succeed of the command succeeds

Comment: If, from the bash shell, you do `command; echo $?`, what does that print?   If it's `0`, then your command is claiming that it succeeded...    If this is the case, then you should either fix `command` to return a proper exit code.   If you can't do that, you might try something like `output=$$(command 2>&1); echo "$$output" | grep -q 'error' &&  \( echo $$output && exit 1 \) || true`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is pretty straight forward, assuming your command returns the appropriate value for success (0) and failure (any other 8bit value):

```
command || exit 1

#(rest of your commands)
```

If your command does not return pertinent values, then you have to evaluate the return status in some other way depending on the goal. Typically, if a command is not returning meaningful values, you will usually want to test its output, so you could for instance have something like this:

```
IFS= read -r output < <(command)
[[ -n "$output" ]] || exit 1
#(rest of your commands)
```

Comment: Actually the second example wouldn't work as a recipe in a makefile, as the second command would be executed in a second shell, and `$output` would no longer be set.   You would have to add a semicolon, and concatenate the lines.   Also, neither of your examples print the error message that OP was trying to print.

Comment: Finally you also don't need the `|| exit 1`, as if a makefile recipe returns false, make will stop processing subsequent recipe lines

Comment: Well, obviously, these were shell examples, not makefile recipes, and it'd output the command's error messages, should it fail, which is what the objective seems to be from reading the question. You must be talking about custom error messages, which does not seem to be the initial intent according to the question.